# Select, Count records for each year based on date using CASE ,and OR inside WHERE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a **USER_POST** table which contains all posts ids that was created by users for example the **USER_POST** with id 1 and whose name = Anthony has created post number post_id= 1

```
//**USER_WORK** table
+----+---------+-----------+--------------+
| id |   name  |  post_id  |     date     |
+----+---------+-----------+--------------+
|  1 | Anthony |     1     |  2017-01-01  |
|  2 | Sage    |     2     |  2017-02-15  |
|  3 | Khloe   |     3     |  2017-06-10  |
|  4 | Anthony |     4     |  2017-08-01  |
|  5 | Khloe   |     5     |  2017-12-09  |
|  6 | Anthony |     6     |  2018-04-27  |
|  7 | Sage    |     7     |  2018-07-29  |
|  8 | Brandon |     8     |  2018-09-13  |
|  9 | Khloe   |     9     |  2018-10-10  |
| 10 | Brandon |    10     |  2018-11-03  |
+----+---------+-----------+--------------+
```

So i would like to get separated data for two specific year in one query based on date so here is my query

```
select user_name,sum(data_year_1) as cnt_data_year_1,sum(data_year_2) as cnt_data_year_2
     from(
            select
                case when up.name is not null then up.name end as user_name,
                case when up.date>='2017-01-01' and up.date<='2017-01-31' then 1 esle 0 end as data_year_1,
                case when up.date>='2018-01-01' and up.date<='2018-01-31' then 1 else 0 end as data_year_2
                from user_post up 
                where ((up.date>='2017-01-01' and up.date<='2017-01-31') OR (up.date>='2018-01-01' and up.date<='2018-01-31'))
                and ........ //other conditions 
                
            )
     group by user_name;
```

the data expected to be selected

```
//USER_WORK table
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| user_name | cnt_data_year_1 | cnt_data_year_2 |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  Anthony  |        2        |        1        |
|  Sage     |        1        |        1        |
|  Khloe    |        2        |        1        |
|  Brandon  |        0        |        2        |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

but the problem is that the query dont return the right result for cnt_data_year_1

```
//result with problem
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| user_name | cnt_data_year_1 | cnt_data_year_2 |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  Anthony  |        0        |        1        |
|  Sage     |        0        |        1        |
|  Khloe    |        0        |        1        |
|  Brandon  |        0        |        2        |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Best regards

Comment: What is the data type of your `up.date` column? If it's DATE, then you should be converting your strings into dates, e.g. `up.date>=to_date('2017-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')`. Also, be careful if your date columns can contain times - a date of `2017-01-31` is really `2017-01-31 00:00:00` - i.e. a date of `2017-01-31 01:23:45` would not be returned by the above query.

Comment: Also, the reason why your data for year 1 is wrong is most likely because of your where clause - you haven't got brackets in the right place - you want `where ((up.date>='2017-01-01' and up.date<='2017-01-31') OR (up.date>='2018-01-01' and up.date<='2018-01-31'))`. And did you really mean to select just January's rows for both years?

Comment: @Boneist Thank you for repleying the column is a date format, so i need to select data where date is from '2017-01-01'  to '2017-01-31' for 2017 and from  '2018-01-01' to '2018-01-31' for 2018, i had correct the where clause but still geting wrong result in the year one

Comment: Boneist advice sounds very good. You could simply use `where extract(month from up.date) = 1` or `where ((up.date >= date '2017-01-01' and up.date < date '2017-02-01') or (up.date >= date '2018-01-01' and up.date < date '2018-02-01'))`. Both consider possible time parts. The second query could benefit from an index on the date column. The first clause is more readable, however, and you could still add a function index, if you wanted so.

Comment: thank you for replying @Boneist  and @Thorsten Kettne ,so what about other conditions?  so it should be like this right? 
 `where ((up.date >= date '2017-01-01' and up.date <= date '2017-12-31' and ........ //other conditions ) or (up.date >= date '2018-01-01' and up.date < date '2018-12-31' and ........ //other conditions ))`
but why i get false result from the first year data_year_1

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/14254a/14):

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
   id NUMBER,
   name VARCHAR2(20),
   post_id NUMBER,
   "date" DATE
);

INSERT INTO my_table (id, name, post_id, "date") VALUES (1, 'Anthony', 1, TO_DATE('2017-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO my_table (id, name, post_id, "date") VALUES (2, 'Sage', 2, TO_DATE('2017-02-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO my_table (id, name, post_id, "date") VALUES (3, 'Khloe', 3, TO_DATE('2017-06-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO my_table (id, name, post_id, "date") VALUES (4, 'Anthony', 4, TO_DATE('2017-08-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO my_table (id, name, post_id, "date") VALUES (5, 'Khloe', 5, TO_DATE('2017-12-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO my_table (id, name, post_id, "date") VALUES (6, 'Anthony', 6, TO_DATE('2018-04-27', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO my_table (id, name, post_id, "date") VALUES (7, 'Sage', 7, TO_DATE('2018-07-29', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO my_table (id, name, post_id, "date") VALUES (8, 'Brandon', 8, TO_DATE('2018-09-13', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO my_table (id, name, post_id, "date") VALUES (9, 'Khloe', 9, TO_DATE('2018-10-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO my_table (id, name, post_id, "date") VALUES (10, 'Brandon', 10, TO_DATE('2018-11-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));

SELECT name
      ,NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN "year" = '2017' THEN "count" END),0) AS "cnt_data_year_1"
      ,NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN "year" = '2018' THEN "count" END),0) AS "cnt_data_year_2 "
FROM
(
  SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "date") "year"
        ,name
        ,COUNT(*) "count"
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "date")
          ,name
) DS
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for replying @gotqn , it didn't work and my query does not use quotes ad aldo that i cant use group by with the select inside the from for some reasons

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is conditional aggregation.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with user_post (id, name, datum) as
  2    (select 1, 'Anthony', date '2017-01-01' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'Sage'   , date '2017-02-15' from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'Khloe'  , date '2017-06-10' from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'Anthony', date '2017-08-01' from dual union all
  6     select 5, 'Khloe'  , date '2017-12-09' from dual union all
  7     select 6, 'Anthony', date '2018-04-27' from dual union all
  8     select 7, 'Sage'   , date '2018-07-29' from dual union all
  9     select 8, 'Brandon', date '2018-09-13' from dual union all
 10     select 9, 'Khloe'  , date '2018-10-10' from dual union all
 11     select 10,'Brandon', date '2018-11-03' from dual
 12    )
```

Query begins here:

```
 13  select name,
 14    sum(case when extract(year from datum) = 2017 then 1 else 0 end) cnt_data_year_1,
 15    sum(case when extract(year from datum) = 2018 then 1 else 0 end) cnt_data_year_2
 16  from user_post
 17  group by name;

NAME    CNT_DATA_YEAR_1 CNT_DATA_YEAR_2
------- --------------- ---------------
Anthony               2               1
Sage                  1               1
Khloe                 2               1
Brandon               0               2

SQL>
```

Comment: thank you for replying @Littlefoot ,what to do in my case if i'm using rank() over(partition) because when i try to adapt this query to mine it doesn't t work

Comment: Why do you insist on that analytic function? What's wrong with that simple conditional aggregation?

Comment: thank you for replying @Littlefoot , it's because i don't get the right result add also i use where clause , so when i use this method its works only for cnt_data_year_2 the but the first dont come right,

Comment: @studentcoding: It is not clear what the problem is. This answer seems the straight-forward solution to your problem. If your where clause is in your way, remove it, I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

There is something confusing here regarding your expected result and your comment, quote: "*... need to select data where date is from '2017-01-01' to '2017-01-31' for 2017 and from '2018-01-01' to '2018-01-31' for 2018*" end quote.
If we stick to the expected result then you can use conditional aggregation as in the Littlefoot's answer or, if for some reason you can't use group by (mentioned in one of the comments), try using conditional use of the analytic function Sum() Over() with DISTINCT keyword (Distinct could be performance costly with large datasets) like here:

```sql
WITH        --  S a m p l e    d a t a  --
    user_posts (POST_ID, USER_NAME, POST_DATE) as
        (
            Select 1, 'Anthony', DATE '2017-01-01' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'Sage'   , DATE '2017-02-15' From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 'Khloe'  , DATE '2017-06-10' From Dual Union All
            Select 4, 'Anthony', DATE '2017-08-01' From Dual Union All
            Select 5, 'Khloe'  , DATE '2017-12-09' From Dual Union All
            Select 6, 'Anthony', DATE '2018-04-27' From Dual Union All
            Select 7, 'Sage'   , DATE '2018-07-29' From Dual Union All
            Select 8, 'Brandon', DATE '2018-09-13' From Dual Union All
            Select 9, 'Khloe'  , DATE '2018-10-10' From Dual Union All
            Select 10,'Brandon', DATE '2018-11-03' From Dual
        )
--  S Q L   --
SELECT DISTINCT
    USER_NAME, 
    Sum(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR From POST_DATE) = 2017 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(Partition By USER_NAME) "CNT_1", 
    Sum(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR From POST_DATE) = 2018 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(Partition By USER_NAME) "CNT_2"
FROM    user_posts
--  R e s u l t     --
USER_NAME      CNT_1      CNT_2
--------- ---------- ----------
Anthony            2          1 
Sage               1          1 
Khloe              2          1 
Brandon            0          2
```

The other instruction (from comment) that you need just January data means that you have to change the condition within the code and that the result would be different too:

```sql
--  S Q L   --
SELECT DISTINCT
    USER_NAME, 
    Sum(CASE WHEN To_Char(POST_DATE, 'MON-YYYY') = 'JAN-2017' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(Partition By USER_NAME) "CNT_1", 
    Sum(CASE WHEN To_Char(POST_DATE, 'MON-YYYY') = 'JAN-2018' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(Partition By USER_NAME) "CNT_2"
FROM    user_posts
--  R e s u l t     --
USER_NAME      CNT_1      CNT_2
--------- ---------- ----------
Anthony            1          0 
Khloe              0          0 
Brandon            0          0 
Sage               0          0
```

**ADDITION**
You mentioned that you are using **RANK**() **OVER**(PARTITION) - not knowing where and how - it could be something like here...

```sql
--  R a n k ( )   --
SELECT    POST_ID, USER_NAME, EXTRACT(YEAR From POST_DATE) "YR",
          RANK() OVER(Partition By EXTRACT(YEAR From POST_DATE) Order By USER_NAME)  "RNK"
FROM      user_posts
Order By POST_DATE
--  R e s u l t     --
   POST_ID USER_NAME         YR        RNK
---------- --------- ---------- ----------
         1 Anthony         2017          1 
         2 Sage            2017          5 
         3 Khloe           2017          3 
         4 Anthony         2017          1 
         5 Khloe           2017          3 
         6 Anthony         2018          1 
         7 Sage            2018          5 
         8 Brandon         2018          2 
         9 Khloe           2018          4 
        10 Brandon         2018          2
```

... if you  want to get the expected result from out of it and if you can not use Group by in any subquery - then you could try something like below (needs Group By, though - but in the outer query):

```sql
--  S Q L   --
SELECT  USER_NAME, MAX(CNT_1) "CNT_1", MAX(CNT_2) "CNT_2"
FROM (  Select    up.USER_NAME,
                  Count(CASE WHEN r.YR = 2017 THEN 1 END) OVER(Partition By up.USER_NAME, RNK) "CNT_1",
                  Count(CASE WHEN r.YR = 2018 THEN 1 END) OVER(Partition By up.USER_NAME, RNK) "CNT_2"
        From      user_posts up
                  --  R a n k ( )
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT    POST_ID, USER_NAME, EXTRACT(YEAR From POST_DATE) "YR",
                              RANK() OVER(Partition By EXTRACT(YEAR From POST_DATE) Order By USER_NAME)  "RNK"
                    FROM      user_posts
                    Order By POST_DATE
                  ) r ON(r.POST_ID = up.POST_ID)
    ) x
GROUP BY USER_NAME 
--  R e s u l t     --
USER_NAME      CNT_1      CNT_2
--------- ---------- ----------
Anthony            2          1 
Brandon            0          2 
Khloe              2          1 
Sage               1          1
```

... and finaly, if you want just January then ...

```sql
--  S Q L   --
SELECT  USER_NAME, MAX(CNT_1) "CNT_1", MAX(CNT_2) "CNT_2"
FROM (  Select    up.USER_NAME,
                  Count(CASE WHEN To_Char(POST_DATE, 'MON-YYYY') = 'JAN-2017' THEN 1 END) OVER(Partition By up.USER_NAME, RNK) "CNT_1",
                  Count(CASE WHEN To_Char(POST_DATE, 'MON-YYYY') = 'JAN-2018' THEN 1 END) OVER(Partition By up.USER_NAME, RNK) "CNT_2"
        From      user_posts up
                  --  R a n k ( )
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT    POST_ID, USER_NAME, To_Char(POST_DATE, 'MON-YYYY') "MON_YR",
                              RANK() OVER(Partition By To_Char(POST_DATE, 'MON-YYYY') Order By USER_NAME)  "RNK"
                    FROM      user_posts
                    Order By POST_DATE
                  ) r ON(r.POST_ID = up.POST_ID)
    ) x
GROUP BY USER_NAME 
--  R e s u l t     --
USER_NAME      CNT_1      CNT_2
--------- ---------- ----------
Anthony            1          0 
Brandon            0          0 
Khloe              0          0 
Sage               0          0
```